# Running Prestashop with php-cli

Tags: prestashop, php

I need to run a CLI (command line interface) script using some of the PrestaShop features. More specifically, I need to run some Admin Controllers.

In order to do so I'm requiring PrestaShop configuration file but it fails loading configuration because during script execution Admin SuperAdministrator is obviously not logged in.

My questions are:

- Which is the best way to run PrestaShop from the command line?
- How can I make PrestaShop think that a user is logged in inside my cli script?

The main problem is here:
**PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function isLoggedBack() on a non-object in /var/{apachevirtualhostpath}/public/www/classes/controller/AdminController.php on line 1805**

I'm running PS **1.5.4.1**.

I've had other issues mainly because of the domain (which is not applicable on cli), but I already solved them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Samples:

```
    //define('PSDIR', '/var/www/prestashop');
    function regen_htaccess() {
      chdir(PSDIR);
      include('config/config.inc.php');
      Tools::generateHtaccess(null, 1);
    }

    function regen_robots() {
      chdir(PSDIR);
      define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', 1);
      include('config/config.inc.php');
      $a = new AdminMetaControllerCore();
      $a->generateRobotsFile();
    }

    function clear_cache() {
      chdir(PSDIR);
      define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', 1);
      $_POST['empty_smarty_cache'] = 1;
      include("config/config.inc.php");
      $x = new AdminPerformanceControllerCore();
      $x->postProcess();
    }
```

The key here is to set `_PS_ADMIN_DIR_` to avoid the `isLoggedBack` failure when you need to instanciate admin/ classes.
But before writing your *prestashop-cli.sh* you may give a look at webservices.

Answer (score 0):

This official documentation page is quite recent, you might not have seen it yet:

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Installing+PrestaShop+using+the+command+line

Cheers!

Comment: I don't think this entirely answers his question; you might look to address the bold text in the question directly, if the linked doc answers it.

Comment: Exactly. The link is about INSTALLING Prestashop from the command line, not USING and RUNNING it via cli.

Answer (score 0):

Use hints from the latest versions of `/index.php` and `/install/index_cli.php` to create a script to load the PrestaShop framework and then run the desired commands directly.

For example, as of PrestaShop 1.5.6.1, if you wanted to delete demo products and orders and initialize a store from the command line, you could use something like the following:

**WARNING: THIS SCRIPT WILL DELETE YOUR DATA! DO NOT COPY AND PASTE WITHOUT UNDERSTANDING WHAT IT DOES.**

```php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

# Initialize PrestaShop framework.  Replace _PS_ROOT_DIR_ with proper path.
require_once(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'config/config.inc.php');

# Include any dependencies that are not already loaded.
require_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'pscleaner/pscleaner.php');

# Execute PrestaShop command(s).
PSCleaner::truncate('catalog');
PSCleaner::truncate('sales');
```